# center rect based on quandrants

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'm a new to the topic and trying the following.
i have 4 quadrants where i want to place a rectangle containing a text this rectangle should have fit the text and be centered to the quadrant, here is my js Code:

as you can see in the code i want to adjust the x attribute of

```
const te = quadrantsGroup
```

thank you

```js
const quad = [
  'Assess',
  'Adopt',
  'Avoid',
  'Analyze',
];

const colors = [{color:'#5899DA'},{color:'#8743B'},{color:'#19A979'},{color:'#ED4A7B'}];


const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 65,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 65,
};

// the chart ought to be wider than taller
const width = 600 - (margin.left + margin.right);
const height = 400 - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

const svg = d3
  .select('.viz')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width + (margin.left + margin.right)} ${height + (margin.top + margin.bottom)}`);
  
  const group = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.top})`);
  
  const quadrantsGroup = group
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'quadrants');
  
  const quadrants = quadrantsGroup
  .selectAll('g.quadrant')
  .data(quad)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'quadrant')
  // position the groups at the four corners of the viz
  .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${i % 2 === 0 ? 0 : width / 2} ${i < 2 ? 0 : height / 2})`);
  
  const qg = quadrants
  .append('rect')
  .data(colors)
  .join('rect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('width', width / 2)
  .attr('height', height / 2)
  // include a darker shade for the third quadrant
  .attr('fill', (d, i) => d.color)
  // highlight the second and third quadrant with less transparency
 .attr('opacity', (d, i) => ((i === 1 || i === 2) ? 0.5 : 0.5));
 
 const quadtexts = quadrantsGroup
  .selectAll('g.quadrant')
  .data(quad)
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'quadtext');
 

  const quadtxtg = quadrantsGroup
  .selectAll('g.quadtext')
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'rectlabels')
 // .attr('width', 10)
  //function(d) {return this.parentNode.getBBox().width + 10;})
  .attr('height', 15)
  .attr('x', width / 7
   )
   .attr('rx', 4
   )
  .attr('fill', '#ffffff');
  
  quadtexts
  .append('text')
  .attr('class', 'qlabels')
  .data(quad)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('dominant-baseline', 'middle')
  .text(d => d)
  .attr('x', width / 4)
  .attr('y', 8)
  .style('text-transform', 'uppercase')
  .style('font-weight', '300')
  .style('font-size', '0.65rem')
  .attr('opacity', 0.9);
  
  const te = quadrantsGroup
  .selectAll('.rectlabels')
  .attr('width', function(d) {return this.parentNode.getBBox().width + 10;})
  .attr('x', width / 5);
  
  console.log("test");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div class="viz"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below is my solution and comments.

All calculation is based on the text width would not longer than it's container.

```js
// I combind label and color together
const quad = [
  {label:'Assess',  color: '#5899DA'},
  {label:'Adopt',   color: '#8743B'},
  {label:'Avoid',   color: '#19A979'},
  {label:'__Analyze__', color: '#ED4A7B'}, // add more text
];

const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 65,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 65,
};

// the chart ought to be wider than taller
const width = 600 - (margin.left + margin.right);
const height = 400 - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

const svg = d3
  .select('.viz')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width + (margin.left + margin.right)} ${height + (margin.top + margin.bottom)}`);

const group = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.top})`);

const quadrantsGroup = group
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(quad)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'quadrants')
  .attr("transform", (d, index) => {
    let x = (index == 0 || index == 2) ? 0 : width / 2,
        y = (index == 0 || index == 1) ? 0 : height / 2;
    return `translate(${x}, ${y})`;
  })
  .each(addLabel);

function addLabel (d) {
  let parent = d3.select(this); // g.quadrants
  
  // background rectangle width fill color
  parent.append("rect")
    .attr('width', width / 2).attr("height", height / 2)
    .attr("fill", d.color);
  
  // insert label rectangle and label text in sequence
  let labelRect = parent.append('rect').attr("rx", 4).attr("fill", 'white');
  let label = parent.append("text")
            .text(d.label)
            .attr("text-anchor", 'middle')
            .attr("x", width / 2 / 2);
  
  // calculate label box width native api: getBBox or getBoundingClientRect
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
  let labelBox = label.node().getBBox(); // or label.node().getBoundingClientRect()
  
  // assign label text and label rectangle appropriate position
  labelRect.attr("width", labelBox.width + 10)
    .attr("height", labelBox.height + 10)
    .attr("x", (width / 2 - (labelBox.width + 10)) / 2);
  
  label.attr('y', labelBox.height + 5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div class="viz"></div>
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for the answer, there is one thing which is missing: if i edit the width of the 4 quandrants the text ist not moving to the middle of the quandrants. ` parent.append("rect")
    .attr('width', width / 4).attr("height", height / 2)` this is basically my problem as i want that the user controls the width of each of the 4 quandrants.

Comment: I don't know how exactly you mean of "user controls the width of each of the 4 quandrants", this control can by dragging resize the quandrants or just fill some input forms. No matter which way you choose it is just a center aligned math problem.